# Performance difference between regex search and normal search

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make few search in text data with different conditions

```
if '@' + company_name+' ' in  content  or '#' + company_name+'\'s' in   content  or ' ' + company_name+'\'s' in   content  or '#' + company_name+' ' in  content  or ' ' + company_name+' ' in  content  or ' ' + company_name+'.' in  content or '.' + company_name+' ' in  content:
```

I am looking for any better approach to do same thing. Is there any better way to write same condition?

If I rewrite the conidtion using `regex`

```
if bool(re.search('@' + company_name+' ',content)) 

 or bool(re.search('#' + company_name+'\'s',content))

 or bool(re.search(' ' + company_name+'\'s',content))

 or bool(re.search(' ' + company_name+'\'s',content))

 or bool(re.search('#' + company_name+' ',content))
```

will it make any changes in performance and time required to execute? I have to test this condition on each documents and in single go I test on 5000 such documents.

Comment: You may try `if bool(re.search(r"[@# ]{}(?: |'s)".format(re.escape(company_name)),content))` and compare with your solution.

Comment: Do note that there's a small difference between @WiktorStribiżew 's regex and your code: The regex will match `@company_name's`. Also, your own regex doesn't match `.company_name<space>` or `<space>company_name.`.

Comment: If this is running multiple times, use re.compile to avoid the overhead of initial regex parsing. There you go even more performance (depenind on context)

Comment: Ok, `r"[@#]{0} |[ #]{0}'s".format(re.escape(company_name))`, but this is not the best pattern.